# Why do we intialize webelement?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Why do we initialize web elements using an initelement method when we use @findBy annotation, whereas in driver.findElement() we don't need to initialize?

```
@FindBy(id="search")
WebElement searchTextBox;

public PageFactoryDemoClass(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because before initializing these objects/elements are not part of the processed code blocks. It is for creating instance that objects, Driver cannot know that they are builded or loaded.

You can think like that, you also cannot use another class before initialize that. If you are asking this question, I think you should check basis of OOP.

[Here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/object-initialization-in-java.html) is a good article about why initialization is important.

Comment: If it is okey for you accept the answer for closing this.@kundankumar